# Any one know what the XPATH for url insude span class onclick=window.open?

Tags: excel, xpath

Hi need advice to find the xpathonurl URL inside span onclick="windows.open..

I use this =XPathOnUrl(B19;"//*[@id='dealerdetail-page']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span")
but the result is text : Gmap Location

I want the result is the google map url (https://map.google.com/?q=..) not the text

```
<span class="button-secondary" title="Petunjuk Arah" onclick="window.open('http://maps.google.com/?q=-6.249028,106.996952', '_blank')">Gmap Location</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have access to xpath 1.0, you can try:

```
//span/substring-before(substring-after(./@onclick,"'"),"'")
```

If you have xpath 2.0, try:

```
//span/tokenize(@onclick,"'")[2]
```

Comment: Halo Jack Fleeting, thank for the answer.
Im using excel the result is #Value

Comment: @DominasiSERP First, you should have mentioned in the question you're using Excel. Second, what is `XPathOnUrl`?

Answer (score -1):

```xml
substring-before(
   substring-after(
      //*[@id='dealerdetail-page']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/@onclick, 
      "'"
   ), 
   "'"
)
```

translation: the value of the `onclick` attribute of the `span`, discarding everything before the first `'` character, and after the next `'` character.

NB this uses the XPath you've given above, but since you haven't provided the full HTML, I've tested a version of the XPath against the XML you *did* supply:

```
<span 
   class="button-secondary" 
   title="Petunjuk Arah" 
   onclick="window.open('http://maps.google.com/?q=-6.249028,106.996952', '_blank')"
   >Gmap Location</span>
```

XPath:

```
substring-before(
   substring-after(
      /span/@onclick, 
      "'"
   ), 
   "'"
)
```

Result:

```
http://maps.google.com/?q=-6.249028,106.996952
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been voted down; it's tested and returns the desired result.

Comment: I see you've updated your question to mention Excel. I assume you're using the "SeoTools for Excel" plugin. It's always a good idea to be explicit in your question about what tools you are using, what version of XPath etc. In this case I don't think the plugin's XPath support extends to performing substring operations, which would mean the best you can do is retrieve the entire `onclick` attribute and process it further in Excel to extract the portion you want.